# CompositeByteBuf has readableBytes return 0

Tags: netty

What's the issue with following code? It always prints 0 for readableBytes, even though there is clearly data in CompositeByteBuf.

```
    private void compositeTest() {
       ByteBuf buf1 = Unpooled.buffer(1024);
       buf1.writeBytes("hello".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
       ByteBuf buf2 = Unpooled.buffer(1024);
       buf2.writeBytes("world".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

       CompositeByteBuf composite = Unpooled.compositeBuffer();
       composite.addComponent(buf1);
       composite.addComponent(buf2);

       System.out.println("Number of components " + composite.numComponents() +
                          ", Composite readable bytes: " +
                          composite.readableBytes()); 

       }
```

The last print statement prints:

**Number of components 2, Composite readable bytes: 0**

I'm using this in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.34.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readableBytes()` is calculated as the buffers `writerIndex - readerIndex`. If you call `composite.writerIndex()` you'll notice that it also returns 0.

Looking at the docs for `addComponent()`:

http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/CompositeByteBuf.html#addComponent(io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf)

`Be aware that this method does not increase the writerIndex of the CompositeByteBuf. If you need to have it increased you need to handle it by your own.`

To make it work correctly you can manually set the `writerIndex()`.

`composite.writerIndex(buf1.writerIndex() + buf2.writerIndex())`

You might want to use `Unpooled.wrappedBuffer()` which will do this for you.

Comment: This behavior, although documented, is mighty confusing. What's the point of CompositeBuffer if it doesn't give me a merged view of the parts. The documentation even says - 'A virtual buffer which shows multiple buffers as a single merged buffer. '

Answer (score 2):

you can use `addComponent(boolean increaseWriterIndex, ByteBuf buffer)` with netty-4.1.x, when method param `increaseWriterIndex` is set true, it can do this for you.