# How to insert a string into the middle of a Netty CompositeByteBuf

Tags: java, netty

I have a `CompositeByteBuf` with some number of buffers that comprise an HTTP request and I want to inject an additional HTTP header field right after the HTTP request line. (I don't want to use the whole HTTP encoder/decoder thing because I'm just proxying the data and don't need to parse all of it as HTTP).

How can I do this using derived buffers and therefore avoid copying the contents of the `CompositeByteBuf`. Every attempt I've made using slice and readSlice has yielded indexoutofbounds errors or Stack Overflow. Can anyone suggest an alternative to the following that does not require copying the whole compositebytebuf?

```
/**
 * Injects an XFF header into pendingBuf 
 */
private void addXForwardedForHeaderToPendingBuf(
                 int pLFpos, 
              String pRemoteIPaddr)
{
    //create a new buffer 
    ByteBuf newBuf = inboundChannel.alloc().directBuffer(); 

    //add the HTTP request line to it
    ByteBufUtil.writeUtf8(newBuf, 
                          pendingBuf.readCharSequence(pLFpos + 1, 
                          CharsetUtil.UTF_8));

    //add the XFF header
    ByteBufUtil.writeUtf8(newBuf, "X-Forwarded-For: ");
    ByteBufUtil.writeUtf8(newBuf, pRemoteIPaddr);
    ByteBufUtil.writeUtf8(newBuf, "\r\n");

    //add anything from the original buffer that came after the request line
    int bytesRemaining = pendingBuf.readableBytes();
    if (bytesRemaining > 0)
    {
        newBuf.writeBytes(pendingBuf);
    }

    //clear pendingBuf
    pendingBuf.removeComponents(0, pendingBuf.numComponents()); 
    pendingBuf.setIndex(0, 0);

    //add newBuf into pendingBuf 
    pendingBuf.addComponent(newBuf);
    pendingBuf.writerIndex(pendingBuf.writerIndex() + newBuf.writerIndex()); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While editing the current bytebuf has the drawback that in the worst case that all bytes needs to be moved, we can exploit the fact that `CompositeByteBuf` have components that we can edit and move around as needed.

We basically want to implement the following steps:

1. Since there could be multiple `Bytebuf`s inside a `CompositeByteBuf`, we want to search the index of the buf we want to modify.

   `ByteBuf` provides the following methods for us to do this:

   - [toComponentIndex](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/CompositeByteBuf.html#toComponentIndex-int-)
   - [toByteIndex](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/buffer/CompositeByteBuf.html#toByteIndex-int-)

   Sadly, these methods won't work correctly in the case when there's an insertion at the end of the string, since this is technically out of bounds for the original buffer, we needed to add a special case for this.
2. We want to implement the special case that we want to insert exactly on a boundary between multiple buffers because we can actually work with zero copy in these cases.
3. If the split index happens to fall in the middle of a bytebuf, we need to split it, and add itself as 2 separate buffers.
4. We need to update the writer index on the composite, [for some reason this doesn't happen by default.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35930080/1542723)

Using the above flow, we can create the following code:

```java
public static void insertString(CompositeByteBuf buffer, int index, ByteBuf insertion) {
    try {
        if (buffer == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("buffer");
        }
        if (insertion == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("insertion");
        }
        if (buffer.readableBytes() < index) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("buffer.readableBytes() < index: "
                    + buffer.readableBytes() + " < " + index);
        }

        // Start by checking the offset where we need to inject the insertion
        int injectionBufOffset;
        int injectionByteOffset;
        if (index == buffer.readableBytes()) {
            injectionBufOffset = buffer.numComponents();
            injectionByteOffset = 0;
        } else {
            injectionBufOffset = buffer.toComponentIndex(index);
            injectionByteOffset = index - buffer.toByteIndex(injectionBufOffset);
        }

        // Optimalize in the case of offset 0
        if (injectionByteOffset == 0) {
            buffer.addComponent(injectionBufOffset, insertion.retain());
            buffer.writerIndex(buffer.writerIndex() + insertion.readableBytes());
            return;
        }
        // Do the split technique
        ByteBuf toSplit = buffer.internalComponent(injectionBufOffset).retain();
        try {
            buffer.removeComponent(injectionBufOffset);
            buffer.addComponent(injectionBufOffset + 0,
                    toSplit.readSlice(injectionByteOffset).retain());
            buffer.addComponent(injectionBufOffset + 1, insertion.retain());
            buffer.addComponent(injectionBufOffset + 2,
                    toSplit.retain());
            buffer.writerIndex(buffer.writerIndex() + insertion.readableBytes());
        } finally {
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(toSplit);
        }
    } finally {
        if (insertion != null) {
            ReferenceCountUtil.release(insertion);
        }
    }
}
```

Since this code is quite complex, we also want to make sure its tested properly, therefore, we need some unit tests (JUnit):

```java
import static test.NettySplit.insertString;

public class NettySplitTest {

    CompositeByteBuf buffer;
    ByteBuf test;

    private void addByteBuf(CompositeByteBuf target, ByteBuf source) {
        target.addComponent(source);
        target.writerIndex(target.writerIndex() + source.readableBytes());
    }

    @Before
    public void before() {
        buffer = ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT.compositeBuffer();
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        ReferenceCountUtil.release(buffer);
        buffer = null;
        ReferenceCountUtil.release(test);
        test = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testSplitting() {
        addByteBuf(buffer, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[]{0, 1, 2, 3}));

        insertString(buffer, 2, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[]{5}));

        test = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[]{0, 1, 5, 2, 3});
        assertEquals(test, buffer);

    }

    @Test
    public void testInsertionStart() {
        addByteBuf(buffer, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[]{0, 1, 2, 3}));

        insertString(buffer, 0, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[]{5}));

        test = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[]{5, 0, 1, 2, 3});
        assertEquals(test, buffer);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsertionEnd() {
        addByteBuf(buffer, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[]{0, 1, 2, 3}));

        insertString(buffer, 4, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[]{5}));

        test = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 5});
        assertEquals(test, buffer);
    }

    @Test
    public void testInsertionSplitEnd() {
        addByteBuf(buffer, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[]{0, 1, 2, 3}));
        addByteBuf(buffer, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[]{0, 1, 2, 3}));

        insertString(buffer, 6, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[]{5}));

        test = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 5, 2, 3});
        assertEquals(test, buffer);
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, now I don't feel quite so badly about not being able to figure that out on my own. Still, it is good to know my instincts were correct and it can be done efficiently. Thanks very much for a thoughtful and thurough answer!